# finding manager id from employee table

Tags: sql

I have a table data like in the below.

```
Emp_id Emp_name Dept_id 
111    aaa       1
222    bbb       2
333    ccc       3
444    ddd       4
555    eee       5
```

Then i want to populate new column manager id as next emp_id from the employee table  like in the below.

```
Emp_id Emp_name Dept_id Manager_id
111    aaa       1       222
222    bbb       2       333
333    ccc       3       444
444    ddd       4       555
555    eee       5       111
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Where is stored manager id?

Comment: Looking by the input and the output it seems the manager and employee are in different departments. Are you sure about the dataset?

Comment: @Dani manager id is not in the employee table. In the output, i've to populate new column manager id as next employee id from employee table.

Comment: @NagaSushmaKallam You (and we) have to know database structure for find manager id

Comment: Column_name   Type Computed Length Prec  Scale Nullable
Emp_ID            int           no                   4         10                0     no
Emp_Name varchar    no            50                                yes
Dept_id              int            no                 4               10               0          no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the value as:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(lead(empid) over (order by empid),
                min(empid) over ()
               ) as manager_id
from t;
```

Perhaps a `select` query is sufficient.  Actually modifying the table is a bit tricky and the best syntax depends on the database.